# Force Service Broker queue into an error state

Tags: sql-server, queue, service-broker

At my work, there has been an ask to test code that is triggered when a Service Broker queue in SQL enters an error state during the conversation. At which point we close it and re-open it.

However, I've tried to set the state for sys.conversation_endpoints to "ER" (error state) and am denied that ability. My question: can you force the service broker queue into an error state, if so, how?

Any help or information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are actually talking about moving a *conversation* into error state, not a queue. To achieve this, simply [end the conversation with error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177521.aspx) from the target endpoint:

```
END CONVERSATION {target-endpoint-handle} 
 WITH ERROR = <my error code>
 DESCRIPTION = '<my error description>';
```

This will end the conversation and enqueue an error message to your service.